# Duplicating rows conditionally / Transform with function that conditionally returns rows

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, apply, pandas-groupby

I would like to create a new column `'derby_one'` by extending the column `'one'` across all rows where the index is `'Derby'` as demonstrated in the `valid_result` below

```
number              one  two  three
country town
AU      Newcastle     0    1      2
        Derby         3    4      5
        Sydney        6    7      8
UK      Derby         9   10     11
        Kensington   12   13     14
        Newcastle    15   16     17
USA     Derby        18   19     20
```

A similar result can be achieved by the `transform` function

```
data.groupby(['country']).one.transform(max)
```

However, I am unsure how to modify this to interact with the indexer

## Example data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(21).reshape(7,3), index=pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[u'AU', u'UK', 'USA'], [u'Derby', u'Kensington', u'Newcastle', u'Sydney']], labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2], [2, 0, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0]], names=[u'country', u'town']), columns=pd.Index(['one', 'two', 'three'], name='number'))

# create test data set
test = data.copy()
derby_one = pd.Series(np.array([0,0,0,9,9,9,18]), index=data.index)
test['derby_one'] = derby_one
```

## Caveats

I don't want to use a join / merge function as my real data set is very large e.g. the following option is not feasable

```
derby_one = data.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'Derby'], ['one']].reset_index()
derby_one = derby_one[['country', 'one']].rename(columns={'one':'derby_one'})
pd.merge(
    data.reset_index(),
    derby_one,
    left_on=['country'],
    right_on=['country']).set_index(['country', 'town']
)
```

Comment: A (now deleted) answer provided a method with `.query('town == "Derby"')` and then used `ffill` to pad out the `np.nan` values. However, this was position dependent and fails when the data is unsorted. 1) I suspect that a combination of `ffill().bfill()` may work though. 2) `.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'Derby']]` is twice as fast as `query` with the same result

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this, letting Pandas align your indexes for you and use `query` filter only those 'Derby' rows then use `groupby` and `transform` to fill NaN values in groups:

```
data['derby_one'] = data.query('town == "Derby"')['one']
data.groupby(['country'])['derby_one'].transform(max)
```

Output

```
number              one  two  three  derby_one
country town                                  
AU      Derby         0    1      2        0.0
        Newcastle     3    4      5        0.0
        Sydney        6    7      8        0.0
UK      Derby         9   10     11        9.0
        Kensington   12   13     14        9.0
        Newcastle    15   16     17        9.0
USA     Derby        18   19     20       18.0
```

Comment: Hi Scott, I've made an edit to avoid position-dependent answers if you run the same without relying on `'Derby'` being at the top of the list your method fails

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane Okay.  I'll modify.

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane Okay, try this.

Comment: ha, I thought you'd gone to all the effort and just deleted it all so I wrote it all in a comment :)

Comment: Any advantage of `transform` over `bfill().ffill()` ? The latter is 5x faster!

Comment: Yeah, you need to keep the fill in the group, so unless it in the first or last position in that group, I think you are going to have to groupby.